# I've Got You Surrounded!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I'm in your house, workplace, and more.
Some say I improve the decor.
To measure me, you measure twice,
But four times to be more precise.

My pet's known for its speed.
My best friend's name is Matt.
I'm usually quite thin,
But can be rather fat.

The name of my main strength-
It happens to some food.
One look at my contents
Can lighten up your mood.

I endure falls and beatings and bangings.
I've even been known to survive hangings.
So spend time with me if you're feeling down.
I will make a big smile out of that frown.

What am I?

Hint:

> I am around the things you love.
>  Bottom, sides, and even above.

Comment: I have an idea but not sure. If I say WP, do you know what I mean? If not, never mind

Comment: @Prim3numbah WP doesn't ring any bells. Maybe it's time for a couple more lines as a hint on this one.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't make all of it fit. That would be nice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***New answer.*** 
 I think I've got it now.  You are a

> picture frame.

I'm in your house, workplace, and more.
Some say I improve the decor.

> True

To measure me, you measure twice,
But four times to be more precise.

> You have to measure the outside of the frame twice (L x W) to see how much space on the wall it will need, and the inside of the frame twice (L X W) to see how large the picture can be/needs to be.

My pet's known for its speed.

> Many picture frames use a [**rabbet**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_frame) on the back to hold the picture and backing.

My best friend's name is Matt.

> Matting is critically important for a nice picture frame.

I'm usually quite thin,
But can be rather fat.

> True.  There are some seriously chunky picture frames out there.

The name of my main strength-
It happens to some food.

> The strength of a picture frame is its [**molding/moulding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_frame). Molding also happens to some food if it sits around long enough, especially food with high moisture content.

One look at my contents
Can lighten up your mood.

> Seeing my family's smiling faces makes me happy.

I endure falls and beatings and bangings.

> I'm thinking of the pictures in our stairwell that I occasionally bump off the wall and they go cartwheeling down the stairs.  They survive a couple of times, and then I have to glue them back together.

I've even been known to survive hangings.

> Pictures often get hung on the wall.

So spend time with me if you're feeling down.
I will make a big smile out of that frown.

> What's that old song about memories and reminiscing about stuff?

===================================================

***Original Answer***
I believe you are a

> rug.

I'm in your house, workplace, and more.
Some say I improve the decor.

> That's true.

To measure me, you measure twice,
But four times to be more precise.

> You measure a rectangular rug in length and width, but you also have to measure the space for it so four total measurements.

My pet's known for its speed.

> Rug rats (crawling) are shockingly fast.

My best friend's name is Matt.

> Or mat (like a door mat)

I'm usually quite thin,
But can be rather fat.

> Most rugs are thin, but some shag or ultra plush rugs are thick

The name of my main strength-
It happens to some food.

> Rugs are tough.  Unfortunately, that happens to food sometimes too.

One look at my contents
Can lighten up your mood.

> Mood (or moud) rugs are a style of persian rug with lovely patterns in the weave.

I endure falls and beatings and bangings.

> Fall down on a rug, no problem.  Beat and bang it to clean it, also no problem.

I've even been known to survive hangings.

> Some rugs are hung as decorations like a tapestry.

So spend time with me if you're feeling down.

> Literally down on the floor.

I will make a big smile out of that frown.

> Who doesn't like laying on the carpet sometimes?

Comment: Great try +1 very creative but some of those don't fit that well. You can edit your answer as more ideas come to to you.

Comment: I was thinking similar but for "My pet's known for its speed." I was thinking rot13(pne crg)

Comment: @cap super creative but that's not it

Comment: @JLee - Good point on the title.  New answer added.  I feel better about this one.

Comment: @JLee - I’ve made enough of them that I should have caught the one about the pet!

Comment: rot13(V gubhtug gur cerfreingvir natyr jnf cerggl fbyvq!)

Answer (score 1):

Why hello,

> CLOTHING! (or CLOTHES)

I'm in your house, workplace, and more.

> We've got closets and people full of you

Some say I improve the decor.

> The clothes people wear set the ambiance of the space, such as dress clothes improving it

To measure me, you measure twice,

> Length and width

But four times to be more precise.

> I'm not a seamstress, but probably also circumference and...

My pet's known for its speed.

> The part of the body nearest the clothing is the hair; a hare is a fast animal

My best friend's name is Matt.

> Clothing likes to hang out at laundroMATs

I'm usually quite thin,
But can be rather fat.

> Much clothing is thin (socks, pants), some is fat (sombrero)

The name of my main strength-
It happens to some food.

> Clothing's main strength is it makes you WARM. Some food is best when warmed

One look at my contents
Can lighten up your mood.

> Um, this is better left unsaid :)...

I endure falls and beatings and bangings.

> In the washing machine

I've even been known to survive hangings.

> On the clothes line

So spend time with me if you're feeling down.
I will make a big smile out of that frown.

> Wearing clothing that please you can cheer you up!

Hint and Title:

> Clothing surrounds you and those people you love

Comment: Good try but that's not it. The intended answer fits much better.